# angular material 2 custom component using mat-auto-complete

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mat-autocomplete

I have multiple forms where users have to specify their country through an auto-complete.

I implemented a service performing the auto-completion (contact backend, handle responses and return suggestions)

Now I want to create a component to reuse throughout all the forms.

This component would depend on:

- the service I mentioned
- a `matInput field`
- a `mat-auto-complete`.

**The component would implement `ControlValueAccessor` and `MatFormFieldControl`**

Parent components would use it like this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <auto-completed-country formControlName="country"></auto-completed-country>
</mat-form-field>
```

The parent component creates the `FormControl` named `country` and specifies its validators (in some forms the country is required, while in others is not).

**Question**

Usually `matInput` is bound to a `FormControl`, and with an auto-complete through the `[matAutocomplete]` directive.

However in my scenario this would not be the case, as `matInput` is not bound to the `FormControl`, which I think it should be ok, as it seems that one can have a `matInput` not bound to any `FormControl`.

However I am worried about the `[matAutocomplete]` directive, which I figured reading the source that it interacts with `matInput` and its associated `FormControl`.

**How should I approach this?**

**Am I making things more complicated than necessary?**

Answer (score 0):

Auto complete without FormControl will work fine.